# ASP.NET Core 3.1 HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient

I see these messages in my debug log:

> [23:29:12 DBG] HttpMessageHandler expired after 120000ms for client 'default' {"EventId": {"Id": 103, "Name": "HandlerExpired"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory"}

> [23:29:22 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items {"EventId": {"Id": 100, "Name": "CleanupCycleStart"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory"}

> [23:29:22 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 1.9126ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items {"EventId": {"Id": 101, "Name": "CleanupCycleEnd"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory"}

> [23:29:32 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items {"EventId": {"Id": 100, "Name": "CleanupCycleStart"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory"}

> [23:29:32 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.1306ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items {"EventId": {"Id": 101, "Name": "CleanupCycleEnd"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory"}

These messages never end, but I do not use any of those in my application.  I have some undisposed object, why do I always have one item?

This is my code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddHttpClient("default", c =>
        {
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
        });
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[This github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/issues/165) discussed a similar issue, and it seems default behavior.

And if you do not want to get the log of `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory` category, you can set it at log level "Information" and higher.

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory": "Information"
```